# Any idea what's wrong with my code on python?

Tags: python, rfid

ihave this code

```
import serial
import time
import datetime
import MySQLdb as mdb

localtime = time.localtime(time.time())

port = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB0", baudrate=9600)
count = 0
nomor =''
start = '\x02'
stop = '\x03'

def mulai():
    print "Silahkan tempel kartu anda"

def no_dosen()
    print "Dosen tidak terdaftar"

    mulai()

def no_jadwal()
    print "Tidak ada jadwal kuliah"

    mulai()

def ada_dosen(dosen)
    print dosen 
    return

def ada_matkul(matkul)
    print matkul
    return

def cek_dosen(no)
    db = mdb.connect("localhost", "azis48", "azis48", "skripsi")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cond1 = "SELECT * FROM dosen WHERE kode_dosen = %s" %(no)
    try:
        cur.execute(cond1)
        hitung = cur.rowcount
        res1 = cur.fetchall()
        for row in res1:
            nama_dosen = row[1]
        if hitung == 1:
            return nama_dosen
        elif hitung != 1:
            return 'null'
    except:
        db.close()

def cek_jadwal(day,time)
    db = mdb.connect("localhost", "azis48", "azis48", "skripsi")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cond2 = "SELECT nama_mk FROM jadwal WHERE hari = '%s' AND waktu = '%s'" %(day,time)
    try:
        cur.execute(cond2)
        hitung = cur.rowcount
        res2 = cur.fetchall()
        for row in res2:
            nama_mk = row[1]
        if hitung == 1:
            return nama_mk
        elif hitung != 1:
            return 'null'
    except:
        db.close()

def cek_pertemuan(matkul)
    db = mdb.connect("localhost", "azis48", "azis48", "skripsi")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cond3 = "SELECT pertemuan_ke FROM acara WHERE nama_mk = '%s'" %(matkul)
    try:
        cur.execute(cond3)
        res3 = cur.fetchall()
        for row in res3:
            pertemuan_ke = row[0]
        return pertemuan_ke
    except:
        db.close()

def base()
    day = localtime.tm_wday
    time = localtime.tm_hour
    no = str(nomor)
    dosen = cek_dosen(no)
    if dosen == 'null':
        no_dosen()
    elif dosen != 'null':
        ada_dosen()
        matkul = cek_jadwal(day,time)
        if matkul == 'null':
            no_jadwal()
        elif matkul != 'null':
            ada_matkul()
            pertemuan = cek_pertemuan(matkul)
            print pertemuan

    mulai()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  mulai()
  while True: 
    data = port.read()
    count += 1
    if count == 1:
        if str(data) != start:
            nomor = ''
            count = 0
    elif 2 <= count <= 13:
        nomor = nomor + str(data)
    elif count == 16 and str(data) == stop:
        base(nomor)
        nomor = ''
        count = 0
```

everytime i run this code, its only print the ada_dosen function from all in def base(), if i stop it with ctrl+c here is the traceback

```
DOSEN3
Traceback(most recent call last):
 file "skripsi.py", line 111, in<module>
  base(nomor)
```

any ide what wrong so all function on my def base() running?

Comment: Please add the complete traceback, seems like you only added the partial traceback

Comment: The definition of base() does allow any variables to be passed as arguments. So either add something to the argument list or remove the argument that is passed.

Comment: Also, for next time, please use a minimal example and include the whole Traceback, so that others can understand your code more easily.

Comment: thats all, if i run the code, after i tap my rfid tag, it only show DOSEN3, after that it only wait so i press ctrl+c to stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues in your code, to highlight a few -

1. All your functions are defined as `def <function name>()` , you do not have an ending `:` , without that you should most probably be getting syntax errors.
2. You have defined your `base` function as `def base()` , but in your main part of the program, you are trying to call it by passing an argument `nomor` as `base(nomor)` , I think you need to change the function defnition to accept the argument as - `def base(nomor):`

Comment: so i should change the function base(nomor) in main ?

Comment: no the definition of the function. the line where the function `base` is defined. Though either would work perfectly.

Comment: sir, can i ask you the next one on my code, i want to open a pptx file with the filename is combination of all data in base so the file name is like this: DosenMatkulPertemuan.pptx